# How to change the color of a list according to a randomly generated banner image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made an array of images to give me a random banner each time I refresh my website. I need the navigation bar under the banner to change to specific colors to match each banner and I can't for the life of me figure it out. 
Here is the array

```
    <script type="text/javascript">  

    <!--//Random Banner image on Page Reload   

    //store the images in arrays below  

    images = new Array(3);   

    images[0] = "<a href='#'><img src='newsbanner1.jpg' </a>";
    images[1] = "<a href='#'><img src='newsbanner2.jpg' </a>";  
    images[2] = "<a href='#'><img src='newsbanner3.jpg' </a>";
    index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);  
    document.write(images[index]);

    //done     
    // -->  
    </script>
```

Now I just need the list that I made as the navigation menu to change background colors to match each image. For example, purple for newsbanner1.jpg, blue for newsbanner2.jpg, and yellow for newsbanner3.jpg. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you show us how you are implementing the navigation menu?

Answer (score 2):

You can make that a json object and add each color along with the image source, then apply the color as a data attribute to whatever element color you want to change, and use the data attribute selector to control the CSS.

```css
[data-color="purple"] {
  color: purple;
}
[data-color="blue"] {
  color: blue;
}
[data-color="yellow"] {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
text
<script>
  images = [{
      'color':'purple',
      'code':"<a href='#'><img src='newsbanner1.jpg'></a>"
    },{
      'color':'blue',
      'code':"<a href='#'><img src='newsbanner2.jpg'></a>"
    },{
      'color':'yellow',
      'code':"<a href='#'><img src='newsbanner3.jpg'></a>"
    }];
    index = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];  
    document.write(index.code); 
    document.body.setAttribute('data-color',index.color);
</script>
```

Comment: I would probably getElementById to get the navbar itself instead of setting it on the document, but whatever, this works great.

Comment: @VSO agreed, but without their code, I'm just coming up with something simple that conveys the point.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of only adding a string add an object with two properties.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

<!--//Random Banner image on Page Reload   

//store the images in arrays below  

images = new Array(3);   

images[0] = {
    color: 'purple', 
    html: "<a href='#'><img src='newsbanner1.jpg' </a>" 
};
images[1] = {
    color: 'yellow', 
    html: "<a href='#'><img src='newsbanner2.jpg' </a>" 
}; 
images[2] = {
    color: 'blue', 
    html: "<a href='#'><img src='newsbanner3.jpg' </a>" 
};

index = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);  
document.write(images[index].html);

var color = images[index].color;
// Now use the color to update or set the navbar 

//done     
// -->  
</script>
```